# React To-Do app: Removing items, but keeping individual state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have run into a problem with my React application. So far there is enough functionality in place to add To-Do items to the list, remove them by index and mark them done (text-decoration: line-through).

When I remove an item that is already crossed out, I would expect the other items to keep their own state, however they don't. Here's what I mean.

[Let's remove the crossed out item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvEH4.png)
[Why is the bottom one crossed out now?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ayv3.png)
Here's my code

ToDoApp.js

```
    import React from 'react';

import Header from './Header';
import AddToDo from './AddToDo';
import FilterToDo from './FilterToDo';
import ToDoList from './ToDoList';
import ListButtons from './ListButtons';

export default class ToDoApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    toDos: []
  };
  handleAddToDo = (toDo) => {
    if (!toDo) {
      return "Nothing was added!";
    }
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      toDos: prevState.toDos.concat([toDo])
    }));
  };
  handleRemoveToDo = (removeIndex) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      toDos: prevState.toDos.filter((toDo, index) => index !== removeIndex)
    }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <AddToDo
          handleAddToDo={this.handleAddToDo}
        />
        <FilterToDo />
        <ToDoList
          toDos={this.state.toDos}
          handleRemoveToDo={this.handleRemoveToDo}
        />
        <ListButtons />
      </div>
    );
  };
};
```

ToDoList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ToDoListItem from './ToDoListItem';

const ToDoList = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h3>To Do List</h3>
    <div>
      {props.toDos.map((toDo , index) => (
        <ToDoListItem
          key={index}
          index={index}
          toDoTitle={toDo}
          handleRemoveToDo={props.handleRemoveToDo}
        />))}
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default ToDoList;
```

ToDoListItem.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ToDoListItem extends React.Component {
  state = {
    done: false
  };
  handleDoneTrigger = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ done: !prevState.done }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p
          className={this.state.done ? "done" : ""}
        >{this.props.toDoTitle}</p>
        <button onClick={(e) => {
          this.props.handleRemoveToDo(this.props.index)
        }}>Remove</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleDoneTrigger}>Done</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: You are using the array index as `key`, which only works if the order of your array is not changed. If you remove a `todo` from your array, the indexes will not be correct anymore. You could instead put a unique `id` property on your `todo` objects and use that as `key`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this piece of code:

```
<ToDoListItem
      key={index}
      index={index}
      toDoTitle={toDo}
      handleRemoveToDo={props.handleRemoveToDo}
    />))}
```

as you set the index as key of ToDoListItem. Instead of index assign some unique key to each element because when you delete an item its index assigned to following item in the list.

This will be helpful to dig more into deep: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: Thanks samee, I have set up 'shortid' to generate unique keys for individual toDoListItems, however now when I have items marked 'done' and I remove or add new items, all class names in the list are reset. Is there a better way to keep track of which toDoListItem has been done?

Comment: can you please show me how are you assigning the unique keys? 

If you are generating and assigning new key in ToDoListItem's render function then on each render it will generate and assign a new key to each component and whenever the component's key gets changed the previous component discarded with its sate and  a new component created with fresh/initial state.

You should only generate the unique key whenever you add a new TodoItem and also save that key with item object in the list. So in render function you can use that key.